# Having issues with viewport tag not working

Tags: html, css, mobile, viewport, meta

I have two webservers..one on my local laptop:
APACHE2 version 2.2.22

and on another machine 
APACHE2 version 2.2.17

The page I'm running is.

http://www.medfieldmarlins.org/sizetest.html

In mobile situations the one on the 2.2.22 which is on my local laptop works as expected.

On the 2.2.17 machine it does not respect the meta tag at all.

I'm very confused and frustrated.

Answer (score 0):

ok have an idiot moment. 
The domain was hosted with Godaddy and was in an iframe...domain forwarding. 
Thus the meta tag was in the iframe...

turned off masking on forwarding and now it is working.